# How to Map Reduce nested arrays with Underscore.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mapreduce, nested, underscore.js

Given:

```
appliedDoses = {
  "_id": "MAIN",
  "scheme": {
    "_id": "MAIN_SCHEME",
    "name": "ESQUEMA CLASICO",
    "vaccines": [
      {
      "_id": "BCG",
      "__v": 0,
      "doses": [
        {
        "_id": "BCG_UNICA",
        "frequencies": [
          {
          "_id": "BCG_UNICA_RECIEN_NACIDO",
          "group_type": {
            "_id": "RECIEN_NACIDO",
            "name": "RECIEN NACIDO"
          },
          "__v": 0,
          "status": true,
          "number_applied": 10
        }, ...
```

What I want is to filter by `group_type.id == "RECIEN_NACIDO"` and `doses[]._id == "BCG_UNICA"` then get a total sumatory of `frequencies[].number_applied`

I tried:

```
async.each(appliedDose, function(scheme){
  async.each(scheme.scheme.vaccines, function(vaccine){
    async.each(vaccine.doses, function(dose){ 
      if(dose._id == getDose) {
        async.each(dose.frequencies, function(frequencie){
          if(frequencie.group_type._id == getGroup) {
            applied += frequencie.number_applied;
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

But my code isn't quite efficiently and I was wondering if MapReduce can be used to improve it. Can somebody give me a hint? Help is much appreciated!

Comment: You've tagged this question with MongoDB (and mention MapReduce), but as described this seems to be a client-side object. Is your given object meant to be a MongoDB document and your query a way of joining data from multiple collections? Some more context on the problem you're trying to solve would be helpful.

Comment: I changed MongoDB to mapreduce tag,and yes I got a MongoDB document from this codeline: AppliedDose.find()
            .where('clue').equals(clue)
            .where( 'applied_date' ).gte( startDate ).lte( endDate )
            .exec( function( err, appliedDose ) {

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by the object you're dealing with so I'll try to deal in abstraction. What you're probably looking to do here is easier and faster if you break it down.

get the collection that results from filtering by: `group_type._id == "RECIEN_NACIDO" && doses._id`

get the array of number_applied's by plucking them out with _.pluck

reduce that with sum: `_.reduce(numAppliedArray, function(sum, x) { return sum + x}, 0);`